# How to make jQueryUI display the right tab from the start?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQueryUI to display some tabs on a page. The tab that is displayed is not always the same, so sometimes I set a different tab as active.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({'active': 1});
    });
</script>
```

I generate this code on the back-end, so it's there when the browser loads the page, but, no matter what, the first tab is displayed for a fraction of a second and only then the active tab is displayed.

How can I make the activate tab be displayed from the start?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({selected: index});
    });
</script>
```

where index is tab number starting from 0

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.2 and I don't see any mention of the 'selected' property. From what I can tell, it's been replaced by 'active'.